# jQuery - function is being called three times

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

I am trying to call "AcceptSuggestion" from javascript. I simulate a click on the "acceptBtn" and then I want to refresh a table row. It is working... but the "AcceptSuggestion" function is being called three times. Anyone knows why? I aleady tried to unbind the "acceptBtn" before clicking but i got no luck.

Here is the update panel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="12" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<div id="123">
<asp:Literal ID="litTable" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
<button id='acceptBtn' onserverclick="AcceptSuggestion" runat="server" style="display: none" />
<button id='acceptAllBtn' onserverclick="AcceptAllSuggestions" runat="server" style="display: none" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="1" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="2" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="3" runat="server" Value="" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="4" runat="server" Value="" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="acceptBtn" EventName="ServerClick" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="acceptAllBtn" EventName="ServerClick" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is the function being called:

```
Protected Sub AcceptSuggestion()

Dim params As String
params = 1.Value
Dim param() As String = Split(params, "|", , CompareMethod.Text)

update(param)

End Sub
```

Well, i guess the problem is not the update panel neither the trigger.

Here is my javascript function to call the button, I can't find anyway to put this to work, and I feel like i've tried everything already.

```
function acceptButton(i) {
                var params = "";
                params += document.getElementById("var1" + i).textContent;
                params += "|";
                params += document.getElementById("var2" + i).textContent;
                params += "|";
                params += document.getElementById("var3" + i).textContent;
                params += "|";
                params += document.getElementById("var4" + i).textContent;
                params += "|";
                params += document.getElementById("var5" + i).textContent;


                var bp = document.getElementById('<%=1.ClientID%>');
                bp.value = params;

                var ri = document.getElementById('<%=2.ClientID%>');
                ri.value = i;

                var Status = document.getElementById('<%=3.ClientID%>');
                Status.value = 1;

                $('#<%=acceptBtn.ClientID%>').off().click();

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I assume that this is because of how Web Forms works :) It fires a different events, you can see the whole page life cycle [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) . I think that the solution of your problem is using on your page Load method or in your Init method and use this code on the top of the method.

```
if(this.IsPostBack)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm already checking if the page is being a PostBack. The Page_Load verification is working as intended, but the AcceptSuggestion function is still being called 3 times.

Comment: Sorry, You haven't posted your controller and I cannot whether you check for PostBack. In that case if I was you I would implement all methods in the page lifecycle set breakpoints, also check the event that calls your function. You can check from where your function is called by console.log(arguments.callee) and see the thing that is called it.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. 
I didn't quite understood your second sentence "In that case if I was you I would implement all methods in the page lifecycle set breakpoints". 
The "console.log(arguments.callee)" thing, i guess you are trying to see how many times the javascript function is being called, if so, it is only being called one time. 
I'm sorry but i'm new to javascript :(

Comment: No with the console log you can see who is called your function. And by implementing all the methods from the web forms life cycle and breakpoint them you will understand more clearly what is going on